How to find an element in a inner part of an cascaded ID-element using edge selenium webdriver with phyton by text
I have a webpage, where sometime a text element is a link and sometimes not.
So I need ...

to find the element
check if its a link
perform an action depending from the result

webcode with Link
<span id="UNIQUE_ID">
    <a role="button" class="CLASS_LINK" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="SOME_CODE">DEFINED_TEXT</a>
</span>

webcode without Link
<span id="UNIQUE_ID">
    <span id="ID" class="CLASS_TEXT" aria-label="SOME_INFO_TEXT">DEFINED_TEXT</span>
</span>

# find text element by ID
txt_element = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'UNIQUE_ID')     # works fine

# now I have to go to the inner part of the cascaded element
inner_part = txt_element.find_element(By.XPATH, "[contains(text(),DEFINED_TEXT)]")    # tried serveral variants, but no one is working

if inner_part.tag_name == 'a':     # perform check, if link
    print("Textelement is Link.")
else:
    print("Textelement is NO Link.")


Can't you do this by just using By.CSS_SELECTOR? #UNIQUE_ID > a should either find an element, or raise a NoSuchElementException which you can catch.

There are any number of ways to do this. The one you were trying is fine, you just needed an updated locator to simplify things.
# find the inner element directly
element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#UNIQUE_ID > *')

# see if it's link
if element.tag_name == 'a':
    print("Text element is a link.")
else:
    print("Text element is not a link.")


Check the code below with explanation:
# Locate the parent <span> with the unique ID
parent_span = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'UNIQUE_ID')

# Check the type of the child element (either <a> or <span>)
child_element = parent_span.find_element(By.XPATH, './*')  # Find the direct child element
tag_name = child_element.tag_name  # Get the tag name of the child element

# Output the result
if tag_name == 'a':
    print("The child element is an <a> tag.")
elif tag_name == 'span':
    print("The child element is a <span> tag.")
else:
    print("The child element is neither <a> nor <span>.")

